# (Closed) java - JSlider not responding

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jinternalframe, jslider

I've been at this for a while and I'm unable to diagnose the reason for the JSlider to not work!

Heres my code snippet. So the slider loads on the screen but the value does not change on dragging. And fUser is a JInternalFrame.

```
    JSlider slider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 1000,1000);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(100);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);
    slider.setValue(200);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
    slider.setLabelTable(slider.createStandardLabels(100));
    JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel();
    sliderPanel.add(slider);
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ce)
        {
            System.out.println("State Changed");
            JSlider source = (JSlider) ce.getSource();
            int value = source.getValue();
            slider.setValue(value);
            slider.repaint();
        }
    });
    fUser.add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Why are you simply setting the `value` of the slider again to the same value which generated the `stateChange` in the first place?

Comment: Your code basically works. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hi. Was my first time posting on stackoverflow and I clearly didnt go about it properly! Thanks for your feedback!